# Wifi coverage area limit of android

Tags: android, wifi

I want to develop an application for android making use of wifi connections. But I need to know the wifi and mobile hotspot coverage area limit of average android devices.

Comment: Why you need to know this? You have application level api's and listeners in android to detect if connection is available, connected or disconnected. You can refer to ConnectivityManger http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html here.

Comment: If u have seen properly, I don't need to detect if the connection is available or not. I need to know the coverage range to know that is it worth to develop the app or not. The app concept is closely related to the range limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to know the coverage range of Android, you would need statistics from every model that you're interested in developing for. In the end, a benchmark for something like that will come down to the hardware.

Without going into deep research, I suppose the best you would be able to do is run an analysis through the theoretical limits of whatever technologies are being taken into use. That though will still have its flaws as well because of variations such as the building the users are in, the atmosphere, the quality of the actual wifi cards. A lot of variation makes that statistic somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use this workaround:
1) Fetch location at the place where your wifi is set-up from the LocationManager.
2) Now register for ConnectivityChange in your application.
3) Start moving away from your wifi.
4) Once you receive the the wifi is gone you'll receive a broadcast receiver and on receiving the broadcast fetch the location again from the GPS.
This way you'll be able to calculate the wifi range manually. I don't know what happens if there are obstructions and all in this case.